# Jersey POST API that has a string body doesn't work on a server (but works locally)

Tags: java, post, jersey, jax-rs

I've created a Jersey POST API, that is getting text/plain as the body. I've tried this API locally and it was working as expected, but after deploying it to a server, I get 415 Unsupported Media Type.

This is the code:

```
@POST
@Path("/dodo")
@Consumes({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response Dodo(String input){
    return Response.status(200).entity(new JerseyDto(input,12)).build();
}
```

This is the error I see in the log:

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class java.lang.String, and Java type class java.lang.String, and MIME media type text/plain was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out what the problem was. We are using shade plugin in order to create a "fat" jar (includes all the dependencies), and there is a problem with Jersey when using this plugin. This is the reason why it was ok when running it locally. You can read more about this problem and the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107376/jersey-problems-with-maven-shade-plugin).