# Error (org.codehaus.mojo) when adding persistence to Maven-Java-project?

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jpa, persistence

When adding persistence to my Maven-Java-project I can successfully build and compile ("Clean and Build Project" in Netbeans, I suppose it does *mvn site*) the project, but I won't be able to start it afterwards ("Run Project" in Netbeans).

I have been trying around for some time without success. For instance I have tried to delete the org.codehaus.mojo plugin in the pom.xml though there was no changement in my success.

Does anyone know this problem? Is there any wrong configuration with my settings for the MySQL database? Or is there an error in the pom.xml? Or in the persistence.xml?

Error from NetBeans IDE:

```
cd /home/myuser/NetBeansProjects/mavenglasses; JAVA_HOME=/home/myuser/jdk1.7.0_51 /home/myuser/netbeans-7.4/java/maven/bin/mvn "-Dexec.args=-jar ${basedir}/target/mavenglasses-1.0.jar" -Dexec.executable=/home/myuser/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building mavenglasses 1.0
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ mavenglasses ---
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:240)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:193)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:264)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:218)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:345)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:412)
    at sun.misc.JarIndex.getJarIndex(JarIndex.java:137)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:674)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:666)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:665)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:638)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:366)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:356)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:355)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:332)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:198)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.850s
Finished at: Sun Feb 23 02:29:03 CET 2014
Final Memory: 6M/105M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project mavenglasses: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Full persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="GlassesPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.treasury.mavenglasses.Hund</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/glasses?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypwd"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Full pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.treasury</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenglasses</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mavenglasses</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>com.treasury.mavenglasses.MainApp</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>Your Organisation</name>
    </organization>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>  
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.29</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I can only guess but the error message shows the direction: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes` so not maven is the problem the calling process. I assume you are starting a java process via exec-maven-plugin:exec ? Without the full pom and configuration it's hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: I have just added the full pom.xml.
Is there some misconfiguration in it?

Comment: Have you tried to call it manually?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do you mean like "mvn site" + java -jar myfile.jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem in NetBeans recently and found a fix now. The problem first started when I added an EntityClass and had NetBeans automatically add the persistence unit, etc.

The problem seems to be caused by the persistence unit adding files to your projects META-INF folder which will use a different technique to calculate the jars signature, or something like that.

To remove these files, add this after the exec-maven-plugin in your pom:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>truezip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>remove-RSA-and-SF-files</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>remove</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${archive}/META-INF</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.RSA</include>
                                <include>**/*.SF</include>
                                <include>**/*.DSA</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

you also need to add the archive variable, which points to your .jar file:

```
<archive>target/projName-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</archive>
```

and finally add to your run task in nbactions.xml:

```
<goal>org.codehaus.mojo:truezip-maven-plugin:1.2:remove</goal>
```

just before:

```
<goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Have the same problem, but solution you describe here not working for me.
BUILD FAILURE
Could not find goal 'remove' in plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2

Comment: Strange, have you defined the goal in your pom.xml?

Comment: Hi @Andrey no, not working for my my **JavaFX** project either.  I did notice that the Netbeans JavaFX POM file uses "classes/" in the final build file, you can see the .SF, etc files in "target/classes/META-INF/" ... Using this information, the TrueZip plugin did at least _find_ the files using:   `<directory>${project.build.directory}/classes/META-INF</directory>`.  However no gainful result, I still get the "Invalid Signature..." error. w.

Comment: See also: [“Invalid signature file” when attempting to run a .jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar) ... This *worked* for me for a **non-JavaFX** project.  Passing it along, in case someone finds the variation that works with **JavaFX**.

Comment: @Andrey .. You might want to watch my question on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842559/valid-jar-signature-for-javafx-projects