# Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes w/ Jetty and Maven Shade Plugin

Tags: java, jetty, maven-shade-plugin

I've seen a few other SO Q&As on this topic, but so far none of the solutions have worked for me:

- ["Invalid signature file" when attempting to run a .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar)
- [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566191/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-securityexception-invalid-signature-file-d)
- [Valid JAR signature for JavaFX projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842559/valid-jar-signature-for-javafx-projects)

We're using Jetty for an open-source application, along with the Maven Shade Plugin:

https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-gtfs-realtime-from-nextbus-cli

We started getting the following error in builds:

```
$ java -jar onebusaway-gtfs-realtime-from-nextbus-cli.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Here's the issue on our issue tracker:

https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-gtfs-realtime-from-nextbus-cli/issues/6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in Jetty:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371954

From the above bug report:

> There is an issue with javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar packaging on which jetty-7.6.1.v20120215 depends:  in the META-INF directory of the javax.servlet jar are found files ECLIPSEF.RSA and ECLIPSEF.SF.
>
> If you generate a jar with maven that uses jetty, you get those 2 files in the META-INF directory of the final jar, and if you run it you get an Exception:
>
> `java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes`
>
> The fix is to exclude the 2 offending files from the generated jars.
>
> The unwanted files can be excluded with the maven-shade-plugin adding to a POM:
>
> ```
> <plugin>
>  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
>  <version>1.4</version>
>  <executions>
>   <execution>
>    <goals>
>     <goal>shade</goal>
>    </goals>
>    <configuration>
>      <filters>
>     <filter>
>           <artifact>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet</artifact>
>         <excludes>
>           <exclude>META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA</exclude>
>               <exclude>META-INF/ECLIPSEF.SF</exclude>
>               <exclude>META-INF/eclipse.inf</exclude>
>         </excludes>
>         </filter>
>        </filters>
>     </configuration>
>    </execution>
>   </executions>
> </plugin>
> ```

Adding the:

```
<filters>
    <filter>
        <artifact>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet</artifact>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/ECLIPSEF.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/eclipse.inf</exclude>
            </excludes>
    </filter>
</filters>
```

... to our `pom.xml` worked for us.