# I have the exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, build, pom.xml

I am new to Kotlin and still do not understand everything. I am trying to build a project in .jar but so far without success. I found many many solutions and tried all of them

[Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes w/ Jetty and Maven Shade Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259504/invalid-signature-file-digest-for-manifest-main-attributes-w-jetty-and-maven-sh)

["Invalid signature file" when attempting to run a .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar)

[Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566191/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-securityexception-invalid-signature-file-d)

[Valid JAR signature for JavaFX projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842559/valid-jar-signature-for-javafx-projects)

but every time the same error pops up:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
```

My maven build:

```
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>io.lavr.utils.any2json.ApplicationKt</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>any2json</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludes>META-INF/*.SF</excludes>
                            <excludes>META-INF/*.DSA</excludes>
                            <excludes>META-INF/*.RSA</excludes>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Please forgive me my ignorance and treat with understanding. Thanks =)

**Changes:**

assembled jar with such a command:

```
jar cvmf src/main/kotlin/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  Application.jar -C target/classes io/lavr/utils/any2json
```

Then I tried to run:

```
java -jar Application.jar
```

but I have error again:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class io.lavr.utils.any2json.ApplicationKt
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/TypeCastException
```

Comment: Can you list content of built jar using 'jar -xvf' command? Does it have what you are looking for?

Comment: I used:
`jar -xvf target/any2json-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep ApplicationKt`
Output: `inflated: io/lavr/utils/any2json/ApplicationKt.class
 inflated: io/lavr/utils/any2json/ApplicationKt$main$1.class
 inflated: su/m13/lavr/ApplicationKt.class`

Comment: The offending class is `kotlin/TypeCastException` Open this class in your IDE, take not of what jar it belongs to and then check if it's present in your aggregated jar created via maven.