# Creating an executable .jar using Intellij

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea

I've got an app which is using few external `jar`s like `mail-1.4` and etc. And now I want to execute my app out of IDE (`IntelliJ`). Also I was following instruction **File>Project Structure>Artifacts** and so on, but my command prompt says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file
igest for Manifest main attributes
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

My `MANIFEST` is almost empty:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: ru.tenet.smsc.SMSC
```

What is wrong?

Comment: When do you get this error? When you build the artifact or when you run your application? I gues the latter so in this case show your command line. And you make take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar

Comment: You can create a single jar with all the dependencies without worrying for the signature exception. Do not add extracted dependencies. For more details see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746177/how-do-i-create-a-runnable-jar-in-intellij-as-i-would-in-eclipse/43855741#43855741

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the jars you extracted to the target jar was signed. The easiest way to fix it is to select "copy to the output directory and link via manifest" in the "Create JAR from Modules" dialog

Comment: In this way it will create a folder with all the jar dependencies inside, not just one jar archive.