# JMH and Swing causes CompletionFailure

Tags: java, jmh

Just tried to switch on JMH into swing's project with the following addition to main POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmh-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and Alexey's plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${artifactId}-with-benchmark</finalName>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>org.openjdk.jmh.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <!--
                                    Shading signed JARs will fail without this.
                                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar
                                -->
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And got Maven's compiler plugin error:

```
Annotation generator had thrown the exception. com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for sun.java2d.pipe.hw.ExtendedBufferCapabilities not found
```

Used Java:

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Does anyone have any idea what was going wrong?
As far as I know [this bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6550655) has been already fixed.

In which directions should I dig in?

Comment: "In which directions should I dig in?" -- provide a minimized test case, obviously.

Comment: Hi, Alex. Just for you: https://github.com/s1ac2x1/jmh-question :)

Comment: as you can see, there is just one class and one POM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, I believe this is an [another](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071778) `javac` bug, that manifests when JMH walks the classes available in current compilation session. While the proper fix belongs in the JDK, we can [work this bug around](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/CODETOOLS-7901278) in JMH, and recover from failures like this. The fix is available with self-built `1.6-SNAPSHOT` now, and will probably be the part of the next patch release (`1.5.1`).