# How to find maven dependency jar files that are signed?

Tags: file, maven, jar, signed

I met an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid
>   signature file digest for Manifest main attributes.

This problem has been solved with this tip:

http://zhentao-li.blogspot.tw/2012/06/maven-shade-plugin-invalid-signature.html

So, how can I find which jar file is signed?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have found solutions.
This question is similar to the one below:

[How can I tell which signed jar is causing maven-shade-plugin to fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199035/how-can-i-tell-which-signed-jar-is-causing-maven-shade-plugin-to-fail)

In my case, bouncy castle is imported with activemq-all.

[dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxhnn.png)