# A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again Exception in thread "main"

Tags: intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, build.gradle, cucumber-java

I am facing a issue while trying to run my executable JAR file for my cucumber project (A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: no manifiest section for
 signature file entry org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator$Envelo
      pedGenerator.class)

Few Important Points : 1.) I am using Idea IntelliJ and created executable JAR
                       2.) I am using Gradle as a build tool
                       3.) I am using cucumber framework and want to run only                         specific test mentioned in my cucumber options using executable JAR

Please find below the complete Error Stack Trace

```
    Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: no manifiest section for
   signature file entry org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator$Envelo
 pedGenerator.class
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.verifySection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Please let me know for any more information required.Read many articles but could'nt able to find any solution.Thanks in advance

Comment: Not received any solution. Can anybody please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Invalid signature file" when attempting to run a .jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar)

Comment: @AbhishekSharma Hi Sir! did you solve the problem, I also facing the same problem.

Comment: This is a generic message. The real problem is on the next line, in this case: "no manifiest section for signature file entry org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator$Envelo
 pedGenerator.class". Hopefully Google can help you with that.