# IntelliJ imported project from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, import

I've imported a project from Eclipse to IntelliJ and I've found that IntelliJ has some issues with making a runnable jar of that project while Eclipse is fine. The error I have when I'm trying to run the runnable jar is :

> Error: A JNI error has occured, please check your installation and try again

And afterwards:

> A Java Exception has occurred

Project runs fine from intelliJ tho. There is just a problem while trying to open runnable jar.

Comment: Maybe similar to [Error when building a .jar using IntelliJ?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36921678/1248974)

Comment: Well solution to select "copy the output directory and link via manifest" works but I would like to have all libs included in the exported jar.

Comment: What about [How to build jars from IntelliJ properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1082580/1248974)

Comment: [Solution for me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31090874/6705466) Thanks for help :)

Comment: Sure, glad to help, congratulations you found the solution :)