# Can not load JMeter test plan on newest JMeter version - jmeter.protocol.java.config.gui.JavaConfigGui: Error setting class

Tags: java, jar, jmeter

I want to load JMeter test plan to the newest version of `JMeter 3`.

The original version of test plan was written on `2.11`.
I have added all needed plugins to `lib` folder:

- Standard set
- Extras Set
- ExtrasLib

Add all needed project jars to `lib` folder.
Updated `jmeter.properties` file:

```
plugin_dependency_paths=../lib/ext/ts/libs
search_paths=../lib/ext/ts/samplers
```

Now when I open the project I see below picture:

[image]

And how it should look:

[image]

All samplers are missed.

Here is snippet from stack trace:

```
2016/06/04 00:51:12 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file: C:\Users\Nazar\Projects\IdeaProjects\fx-performance-tests\jmetertest\FXLoadTesting-rmi.jmx 
2016/06/04 00:51:12 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.java.config.gui.JavaConfigGui: Error setting class:'com.fx.test.sampler.rmi.search.post.PostFreightSearchSampler' in JavaSampler Post Freight Search, check for a missing jar in your jmeter 'search_paths' and 'plugin_dependency_paths' properties 
2016/06/04 00:51:13 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.java.config.gui.JavaConfigGui: Error setting class:'com.fx.test.sampler.rmi.search.post.PostVehicleSearchSampler' in JavaSampler Post Vehicle Search, check for a missing jar in your jmeter 'search_paths' and 'plugin_dependency_paths' properties
```

It works only at `2.11` version of JMeter. Not at `2.13` or `3`.

***Is it correct behaviour? Or I am missing something important for loading `jmx` file?***

Comment: you may copy paste files of your test plan group wise.

Comment: @bajrangi Do you mean copy from `2.1` to `3`?

Comment: yes i mean it.i mean to say don't load jmx file once. move file one by one if possible.and check where it is getting problem. if your recordings files moved successfully to newer version then i think it's not a big deal to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the JARs to JMeter CLASSPATH.

Then it will work - At least in my case.

Comment: just add to `lib` folder directly? I have tried to use `plugin_dependency_paths` and `search_paths` variables from `jmeter.properties` file.

Comment: In my linux machine is like this:
/root/jmeter3/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/ext

Answer (score 1):

You most probably did not copy to lib folder a jar that contains the class:

- com.fx.test.sampler.rmi.search.post.PostFreightSearchSampler

Comment: I did it and specify this at `jmeter.properties`

Comment: What is the jar that contains it ?