# How to stop maven-shade-plugin from blocking java.util.ServiceLoader initialization of opensaml-impl types

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin, opensaml

When using OpenSAML 3, you must first load components from the `opensaml-saml-impl` artifact with the following line of code:

```
InitializationService.initialize();
```

This [uses `java.util.ServiceLoader` to load any type which implements `Initializer`](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OS30/Initialization+and+Configuration).

When I write a test and run it with `mvn integration-test`, this works fine, and I can see that everything has loaded:

```
Assert.assertTrue(
    XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport
        .getUnmarshallerFactory()
        .getUnmarshallers()
        .size() > 400);
```

However, my project uses `maven-shade-plugin`. The condition above is *not* true if I package the code into an uber-jar:

```sh
mvn package
java -jar /path/to/my.jar
```

In this case I observe that only 9 unmarshallers have loaded (those in `opensaml-core`, as opposed to those in `opensaml-saml-impl`. However, when I watch the output of `mvn package`, I can see that the types *are* included in the shaded jar:

```
[INFO] Including org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl:jar:3.2.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.opensaml:opensaml-profile-api:jar:3.2.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.opensaml:opensaml-messaging-api:jar:3.2.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-api:jar:3.2.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-api:jar:3.2.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.opensaml:opensaml-soap-api:jar:3.2.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.opensaml:opensaml-storage-api:jar:3.2.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.opensaml:opensaml-security-impl:jar:3.2.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.opensaml:opensaml-security-api:jar:3.2.0 in the shaded jar.
```

I can work around this issue with the following dumb code:

```
private static void initManuallyInsteadOfWithInitializationServiceSoThatMavenShadePluginDoesNotRemoveThem() throws InitializationException {
    new ApacheXMLSecurityInitializer().init();
    new ClientTLSValidationConfiguratonInitializer().init();
    new GlobalAlgorithmRegistryInitializer().init();
    new GlobalParserPoolInitializer().init();
    new GlobalSecurityConfigurationInitializer().init();
    new JavaCryptoValidationInitializer().init();
    new SAMLConfigurationInitializer().init();
    new org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLObjectProviderInitializer().init();
    new org.opensaml.xmlsec.config.XMLObjectProviderInitializer().init();
    new XMLObjectProviderInitializer().init();
}
```

This utterly defeats the point of the plugin system, but it does allow my program to function.

For reference, here's the relevant bits of `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>com.example.Server</Main-Class>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/services/io.vertx.core.spi.VerticleFactory</resource>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <artifactSet>
                </artifactSet>
                <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-fat.jar
                </outputFile>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <!-- Fix java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
                             when server starts inside Docker container due to inclusion of OpenSAML and use of
                             uber-jar / maven-shade-plugin. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6743609 -->
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                    <filter>
                        <!-- This was one of my attempts to fix the problem.
                             Unfortunately, it doesn't work. -->
                        <artifact>org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl</artifact>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Don't use `AppendingTransformer` for the `META-INF/services`, you can just use [`ServicesResourceTransformer`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer). This may be the issue. Did you check inside the fat JAR what was present under `META-INF/services`?

Comment: Just changing `AppendingTransformer` to `ServicesResourceTransformer` gives me the error `Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.0.0:shade for parameter transformers: Cannot load implementation hint 'org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServiceResourceTransformer`. (Also tried updating to shade 3.0) Am I misunderstanding you? I'm pretty naïve about Shade, sorry!

Comment: You just missed an `s` in `Services` (not `Service`). And you wouldn't need the `<resource>` element under it either.

Comment: That looks like it might have done the trick! I'm going to do an end to end test to make sure it didn't break anything else, but I do see the unmarshallers loading

Comment: @Tunaki please add this as an answer so I can award you credit if the end to end test passes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you're using the Maven Shade Plugin with dependencies using the `ServiceLoader` API, you should use the [`ServicesResourceTransformer`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer), which is dedicated to merge together the files. If the plugin is [relocating classes](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html), it will also relocate properly the class names in each service file, unlike the `AppendingTransformer`.

So you can just replace your current `AppendingTransformer` with

```xml
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
```

It will make sure that every service file under `META-INF/services` of your dependencies are merged, without the need to declare them all.