# java.lang.ClassFormatError error in JMH Maven project

Tags: java, maven, jmh, classformaterror

I am trying to create a project for micro benchmarking `Java` code using [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). I am following the steps mentioned in [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html) tutorial. I created the project using the following Maven command.

```
 mvn archetype:generate
      -DinteractiveMode=false
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.openjdk.jmh
      -DarchetypeArtifactId=jmh-java-benchmark-archetype
      -DgroupId=com.jenkov
      -DartifactId=first-benchmark
      -Dversion=1.0
```

Here is the generated pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.jenkov</groupId>
<artifactId>first-benchmark</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>JMH benchmark sample: Java</name>

<!--
   This is the demo/sample template build script for building Java benchmarks with JMH.
   Edit as needed.
-->

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmh-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jmh.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
        <version>${jmh.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!--
        JMH version to use with this project.
      -->
    <jmh.version>1.20</jmh.version>

    <!--
        Java source/target to use for compilation.
      -->
    <javac.target>1.8</javac.target>

    <!--
        Name of the benchmark Uber-JAR to generate.
      -->
    <uberjar.name>benchmarks</uberjar.name>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerVersion>${javac.target}</compilerVersion>
                <source>${javac.target}</source>
                <target>${javac.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${uberjar.name}</finalName>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>org.openjdk.jmh.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <!--
                                    Shading signed JARs will fail without this.
                                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar
                                -->
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Here are the contents of the source file MyBenchmark.java

```
package com.jenkov;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;

public class MyBenchmark {

    @Benchmark
    public void testMethod() {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int sum = a + b;
    }

}
```

On building using `mvn clean install`, I get the following two warnings (along with other messages not shown here)

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable de
    bug logging for more details

[WARNING] error reading C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-math3\3.2\commons-math3-3.2.jar; invalid LOC header (bad sig
    nature)
```

On running using the command `java -jar target/benchmarks.jar`, I get the following error

```
 # JMH version: 1.20
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0_172, VM 25.172-b11
# VM invoker: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172\bin\java.exe
# VM options: <none>
# Warmup: 20 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 20 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: com.jenkov.MyBenchmark.testMethod

# Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:06:40
# Fork: 1 of 10
# Warmup Iteration   1: <failure>

java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at com.jenkov.generated.MyBenchmark_testMethod_jmhTest.testMethod_Throughput(MyBenchmark_testMethod_jmhTest.java:107)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.BenchmarkHandler$BenchmarkTask.call(BenchmarkHandler.java:453)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.BenchmarkHandler$BenchmarkTask.call(BenchmarkHandler.java:437)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am on Windows 7 32 bit OS. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Plugin version you are using (2.2) is 5 years old. Try upping it to the latest 3.1.1

Comment: @diginoise I upped the shade plugin version to 3.1.1. The problem remains the same.

Comment: I am getting two warnings on running mvn install. Do they provide any clue?

Comment: For start: delete directory '3.2'  from C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-math3 from the message looks like the dependency download was corrupted. And rebuild the project.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj That solved it! Thanks.

Comment: Cool it helped.