# JavaFX 12 - Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jar, jarsigner

Im developing a sample of JavaFX 12, but when generate a JAR file to execute i get this error:

```
java -jar target/JRPrintPreview-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:336)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:269)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:316)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:230)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:758)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.ensureInitialization(JarFile.java:1035)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.ensureInitialization(JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.java:69)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:870)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:788)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:415)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:760)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:655)
```

My sample is here:
https://github.com/prsolucoes/jrprintpreview

And you can test with commands in terminal:

```
mvn clean  
mvn compile
mvn package
java -jar target/JRPrintPreview-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I put a command to sign the jar:

```
mvn jarsigner:sign
```

But don't make any effect (is it necessary?).

I search a lot and tried thing like remove all MANIFEST RSA and other signature files etc.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see from your `pom.xml` that you are using the maven shade plugin to produce your JAR. This will basically bundle all of your dependencies into a single (uber-) JAR file. The uber Please have a look at the following answer which may potentially fix your problem:
[For those who got this error when trying to create an uber-jar with maven-shade-plugin [...]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743609/9977691)

See also the following [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar/6743609#comment95436689_6743609) on the same answer which explains what the issue might be:

> The signature files are there to indicate that the contents of this jar have these files. When you make an uber jar, you're adding a bunch more files to the jar, and thus the signature is not correct. If you really wanted, you could re-sign the new jar, but of course it would be with your signature, not the old one. Alternatively, you could not distribute the uber jar, but instead include the signed jar as a separate file, but then that defeats the purpose of an uber jar in the first place. – LadyCailin Jan 22 at 12:45

Comment: Hi, i already do it, but when remove this files and try execute the JAR i get:  

```Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application```

Comment: I have finished the project with the fix. We need a launcher class for JavaFX instead of only Application class. I updated the repository with the fixes. I put some other issues on github, will be nice if you could help too. Thanks. This problem was solved.