# How to fix this error in Java - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: java

I built a jar file named `jar1` using maven.

I am using the above jar in a standalone Java application. When I run this app, I get this error:

```
at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:238)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:192)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:316)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:450)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:776)
    at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:77)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:160)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:442)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at Hello.main(Hello.java:6)
```

How can I fix this issue? Pls help!

Comment: Could you post text of you Hello.java class?

Comment: How do you run you application? Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar

Comment: `jar1` contains SQL Server JDBC jar in it as well. Am wondering if it's certificates are causing this issue