# Jar Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

I have a google cloud app engine application, this application is implemented with Java 11, and is possible to compile it. But for some reason when I deploy I on the app engine google cant create an instance of this application.

When I test the Jar by command: `jarsigner -verify <APP-JAR-NAME>`

I will get this error message: `jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes`

Here is my POM configuration for Maven Shade plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>${exec.mainClass}</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Do you please have any idea about what can be wrong or how should I try to fix it?

Thanks for every help.

Answer (score 2):

It may be caused by one of your dependencies.
when there is some of your dependencies signed , you can face this kinds of issues.

The solution listed here may help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743609/15353227

Comment: It didn't help, I am now desperate... if you help me to fix it I will pay you 150 USD  if you are interested write me at tom4@seznam.cz we can discuss details.