# JMH + Maven. BenchmarkList gets in wrong JAR

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml, jmh

I've encountered a little problem with a project that I considered finished.
It includes three parts -- the main class for which the whole project was created (a quadruple-precision floating-point number with necessary arithmetic), a set of tests for it, and a benchmarking tool for it which uses `JMH`. Accordingly, the `pom.xml` is supposed to build three jar-files -- `Quadruple-1.0.0.jar`, `Quadruple-1.0.0-tests.jar`, and `benchmarks.jar`. And it does, but the problem is that it puts `BenchmarkList` in the `Quadruple-1.0.0-tests.jar` instead of `benchmarks.jar`.

Thereafter, an attempt to execute the benchmarks running the `benchmarks.jar` fails with the message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ERROR: Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList
       at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.AbstractResourceReader.getReaders(AbstractResourceReader.java:98)
       at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.BenchmarkList.find(BenchmarkList.java:124)
       at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.internalRun(Runner.java:253)
       at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:209)
       at org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(Main.java:71)
```

Below is the relevant part of the `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <javac.target>1.8</javac.target>
  <jmh.version>1.29</jmh.version>
  <uberjar.name>benchmarks</uberjar.name>
  <junit.jupiter.minorVersion>2.0</junit.jupiter.minorVersion>
</properties>
  ...
<build>
  <plugins>
  
    ....  
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <finalName>${uberjar.name}</finalName>
            <transformers>
              <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <mainClass>org.openjdk.jmh.Main</mainClass>
              </transformer>
              <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
            </transformers>
            <filters>
              <filter>
                <!--
                    Shading signed JARs will fail without this.
                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar
                -->
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                  <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                  <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </filter>
            </filters>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>test-jar</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>test-jar</goal>
          </goals>
          
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>
                    com.mvohm.quadruple.test.QuadTest
                </mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
          
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

At the same time in a neighbor folder I have a very similar project, which is actually just a previous version of the benchmarking tool, and it builds and works fine. After a number of attempts to figure out what is the reason of such a difference in their behavior, their `pom`s became almost identical. The only difference is that the separate benchmarking project has one additional dependency (to import `Quadruple`), and the names of the projects are different, and there's no `test` subfolder in the `src` folder of the benchmarking project, thus the `Quadruple_Benchmarks-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar` contains nothing except `MANIFEST.MF`.

What may be the reason of getting `BenchmarlList` to the wrong `jar`? Generally, who is responsible for putting it in the `benchmarks.jar` and not in any other `jar`?

If any additional information turns out to be relevant and can help clarify the situation, I'm ready to promptly provide it. The complete `pom`s (in their previous states, yet with the same behavior) are accessible at github:

https://github.com/m-vokhm/Quadruple/blob/master/pom.xml, (main project)

https://github.com/m-vokhm/QuadrupleAddendum/blob/master/QuadBenchmarks/pom.xml (old benchmarks)

Comment: The recommended way to run JMH benchmark is to use Maven to setup a standalone project, using JMH as recommended may avoid this situation.