# using org.eclipse.jgit-6.4.0.202211300538-r.jar getting error java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: intellij-idea, artifact, onejar

I am using "org.eclipse.jgit-6.4.0.202211300538-r.jar" in a java project with maven. When I run the program from Intellij everything is fine and the program works perfectly. When I build an Artifact out of this project and run it on command line I get the error "java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes".

I know this jar file is a signed jar so I copied the JAR file to another directory and extracted it and deleted the *.RSA and *.SF files and ran it, doesn't work. I also extended my pom.xml file with all the suggestions found online like "excludes", "plugins" and much more, still doesn't work. May be you guys from StackOverflow know how can I create a single JAR-file which uses this jar and doesn't give the error. So how to get rid of this security error which does NOT come out when I run the program in Intellij but appears when I run it on a command line with java -jar

Comment: You can try to create a JAR with excluded files via 'maven-shade-plugin' as described https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743609/12844632

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I added the configuration to the pom.xml file right after <dependencies> block like this:
<build>
<plugins>
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.1</version>
  <executions>
   <execution>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
     <goal>shade</goal>
    </goals>
     ----- the configuration block -----
   </execution>
  </executions>
 </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

Then I built the Artifact from Intellij and then "java -jar MyApp.jar".
Unfortunately it does not work.