docx4j tracking changes implementation
Hello fellow programmers,
I am having trouble in implementing the docx4j tracking changes to one of my projects I wanted to ask. (quick FYI before I go further I am by all means not an java expert.) So, I want to use the docx4j java library but this whole maven thing is quiet new to me. So I am wondering if any one can quickly explain quickly how to use the library properly, and implement the tracking change.
I have already tried implementing it my creating a separate maven project and importing/copying the tracking changes code provided by the docx4j. And it has worked but I am not sure how to implement it into my own project in python and I am not sure whether if that's possible.
So my ideal goal is to just to be able to implement the accept tracking changes of dox4j in a python function.
Many thanks in advance.
This is how my code looks like now.
package org.example;


import java.io.File;
import org.docx4j.Docx4J;
import org.docx4j.XmlUtils;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils;


import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Templates;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class AcceptTrackingChanges {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



        // Load the docx
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("Student_report.docx")));

        // Load the XLST
        Source xsltSource  = new StreamSource(
                ResourceUtils.getResource(
                        "AcceptChanges.xslt")
        );
        Templates xslt = XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(xsltSource);

        MainDocumentPart mdp = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

        DOMResult contentAccepted = new DOMResult();

        // perform the transformation
        mdp.transform(xslt, null, contentAccepted);

        // replace the contents in the WordprocessingMLPackage
        org.w3c.dom.Document domDoc = (org.w3c.dom.Document)contentAccepted.getNode();
        mdp.setContents(
                mdp.unmarshal(domDoc.getDocumentElement()));

        System.out.println(mdp.getXML());

        // Save it
//        if (SAVE = true) {
//            String outputfilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/PI Onsior qrd pi en - tc -accepted.docx";
//            Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, new File(outputfilepath), Docx4J.FLAG_NONE); //(FLAG_NONE == default == zipped docx)
//
//            System.out.println("Saved: " + outputfilepath);
//        }

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Accepted_changes.docx");
    }



}

This is the pom.xml file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>
        fat jar
    </description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--  mvn package

                filters avoid "Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes"
                https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743609/1031689
                -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
                            <!--
                            <relocations>
                              <relocation>
                                <pattern>org.apache.http</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>org.docx4j.apache.http</shadedPattern>
                              </relocation>
                              <relocation>
                                <pattern>org.apache.commons.logging</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>org.docx4j.slf4j.apache.commons.logging</shadedPattern>
                              </relocation>
                            </relocations> -->

                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!--  don't deploy this jar to Maven Central -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl</artifactId>
            <version>11.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.4.9</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There are 2 parts to this.
The first part is the generic question of how to invoke Java from Python. A Google search https://www.google.com/search?q=invoke+java+from+python produces https://rsewiki.liacs.nl/calling_java_from_python which is a good overview of your alternatives, including py4j, jpype and others.
The second part is the docx4j/Maven/Java end.  You've already created a separate maven project which does what you want, which is good. It may be convenient to create a single "fat" jar which contains all necessary dependencies. This way, you can deploy a single file.  https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/VERSION_11_4_12/docx4j-bundle/pom.xml shows you how docx4j does this with the maven-shade-plugin.  You can add this to your own pom.xml then do mvn package.

thank you for your response JasonPlutext. I wanted to ask few more questions like in the java for the tracking changes it also has the extends from the main class or the tracking changes class. Can I adjust it by adding a input file path from user input from a R shiny application. I know this is deviating from the first post. Like is that feasible?

I have now included my code in the questions.

for use from rShiny, see rJava.  You should probably make a separate question if you have questions on this.   Generally you'd have a main method, not extending anything, but this setup may change depending on what integration framework you are using...

Yes apologize about that, I just came into my mind as an alternative. But thank you I will make a another post if needed regarding the Rshiny use cases. once again many thanks for your guidance and time.
